# What does an ivar contain?

Tags: objective-c, ivar

in the header file, an ivar structure  has three members:-

name, type and offset.

I guess name is for storing the name of the variable.

Offset is for storing distance in bytes from the start of the structure.

Please tell me if I am right about these two ? can anyone explain me What is type for ?
Is it the datatype or the scope telling whether it is public ,private or protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a C string containing the instance variable's type encoding. See [Type Encodings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH100-SW1) in your local copy of Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide.

You should not access `Ivar` fields directly, though, because `Ivar` is an *opaque type*. It's better to use `ivar_getTypeEncoding()` for that.

Comment: Then how is the information regarding scope of the variables stored like public,private and protected ?

Comment: The scope specifier is a compiler directive. As far as I know, it does not affect the runtime, it just generates errors during compilation. You can access any ivars at run time, regardless of the scope directives. And yes, you are correct about ivar name and offset.

Comment: I am not accessing ivar's members, I was just reading this pdf 
http://algorithm.com.au/downloads/talks/objective-c-internals/objective-c-internals.pdf

and that lead me to the header file.
I know from Objective-C 2.0 onwards, they have made these structures opaque and we should use runtime's accessor methods to access them.